# Access SQL - How do I return a boolean if a joined row exists or not

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm putting together a query for the datasource for a tabular form. Amongst other data, I want to show a checkbox if a row exists in a joined table and return it as a field for the checkbox to bind to.

Can the boolean be retrieved with one query, or will it have to be a fudge with VBA?

Comment: then you must use an outer join and perform iif(isnull(field), true, false)

Comment: I think I have this working, but shouldn't that be `iif(isnull(field), false, true)` so that it returns false if it is null and true if it exists?

Comment: i just put the iff(condition, true,false) for you. its up to you what you want to replace it with.

Comment: Great thanks, write it as an answer please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use an outer join and perform iif(isnull(field), true_value, false_value)